# Проблемы с составлением SQL запроса

Tags: sql, база-данных, запрос

Не получается составить SQL запрос. Вот таблица ЗАНЯТИЯ:

```
КОД PK INT
КЛИЕНТ_КОД INT
УСЛУГА_КОД INT
ДЕНЬ_НЕДЕЛИ INT
ВРЕМЯ TIME 
ТРЕНЕР_КОД INT
ПРОДОЛЖИТЕЛЬНОСТЬ INT
```

Также существует таблица ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛИ:

```
КОД PK INT
ФИО VARCHAR
ЛОГИН VARCHAR
ПАРОЛЬ VARCHAR
```

Я хочу сделать запрос, который выводит таблицу ЗАНЯТИЯ в таком виде:

```
КОД
КЛИЕНТ_ФИО
...
ТРЕНЕР_ФИО
```

Но дело в том, что первичный ключ в таблице клиенты и в таблице тренеры это внешний ключ таблицы ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛИ, поэтому я не могу получить ФИО КЛИЕНТА одновременно с ТРЕНЕРОМ.

Вот мой запрос:

```
SELECT занятия.код AS КОД, тренер_код, пользователи.ФИО AS КЛИЕНТ, 
услуги.наименование AS УСЛУГА, дни_занятий.день AS ДЕНЬ, время AS ВРЕМЯ, 
пользователи.ФИО AS ТРЕНЕР, продолжительность AS ПРОДОЛЖИТЕЛЬНОСТЬ

FROM дни_занятий, пользователи, услуги, занятия, тренеры

WHERE услуга_код = услуги.код AND клиент_код = пользователи.код AND 
дни_занятий.код = день_недели AND тренер_код = тренеры.пользователь_код
```

Comment: А в чём тут собственно проблема?

Comment: Спасибо. Сам не знал как нагуглить такой вопрос.

Comment: @ИльдарСульбов Да, это частая проблема, что бы нагуглить надо уже знать решение, в данном случае слово "Алиас" :)